SATA disks appearing as removable and mysteriously unmounting
I have two disks that I moved over from an older Windows system, formatted NTFS.  When I boot and log in, they're mounted in the /media/mark directory which I'm given to believe means they were identified as removable, even though they aren't.  The more mystifying bit is that I will lose access to those disks with no warning while my system is sitting idle.
I haven't seen anything in the Disks utility that would help me figure it out.
As asked, the contents of /etc/fstab minus some boilerplate comments at the top.
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=1b8c6528-3b99-4ae9-bae1-9868aeb04b20 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=5E6C-EC6D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

I am currently experimenting with adding the disks to the file.

"I haven't seen anything in the Disks utility that would help me figure it out."   how about the UUID of the disks and correct setup in /etc/fstab?

@graham /etc/fstab is mostly empty.  The disks certainly aren't in there.

you should add the contents of fstab to your question using code formatting

"When I boot and log in, they're mounted..." in which case you wil then see them in the Disks utility. That will provide the UUID. Is this Ubuntu 24.04 by any chance (you didn't specify as you should do) as that may now have significance with NTFS formatted drives.

@graham sorry, I should have anticipated that requirement.  It's Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.  And yes, Disks is able to show the drives even though they're not mounted.

There is nothing wrong with mounting this partitions under /media. They are removable since they can be unmounted. Even if you use fstab, you should use a subfolder of /media, if they are mounted there, they will be displayed as drives in your filemanager. If you mount them somewhere else, this is not the case, you'd have to access them by browsing to the mountpoint.

@mook765 you took the words right off my keyboard

you may find this ask ubuntu question helpful

If NTFS, did Windows set fast startup/hibernation flag. Then NTFS driver will not default mount to prevent loss of data when hibernation restored. You may be able to manually force mount read only. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
If not dual booting with Windows best not to use NTFS as you cannot run chkdsk or other repairs from Linux.

@oldfred I do not know what Windows did, although it's likely that I did a clean shutdown.  The disks are NTFS because they were used exclusively on Windows for many years.  I only moved them because the Windows system died.
